# How to automate image processing so all images are the same size with the same matte?

Tags: gimp, batch-processing, canvas

I have a bunch of 1800x1800 pictures. I need to individually put each image onto a 2200x2200 canvas and then save/export it. Is there a way I can batch this?

To further explain, I need to add a 400 pixel white trim to each side of each picture. Right now I'm using gimp and I'm making a new canvas that's 2200x2200 and adding the picture as a layer and then exporting, and then repeating for each one.

Is there a way that I can automate this or do this multiple pictures at once?

Comment: Some batch image processing in GIMP can be done with a plugin called BIMP (Batch Image Manipulation Plugin).  Check it out https://alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/ - I'm not entirely sure of all it's capabilities but worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

With [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#border), as simple as

```
convert Source.png -bordercolor blue -border 400 Target.png
```

if needed you can define different H/V borders:

```
convert Source.png -bordercolor blue -border 200x100 Target.png
```

Depending on IM version, `convert` can also be `magick` or `magick convert`

If you want to update the original images then use

```
[magick] mogrify -bordercolor blue -border 100 Image.png
```

This form makes it simple to update several images in one command(*):

```
[magick] mogrify -bordercolor teal -border 100 Image*.png
```

(*) One can also use wildcards with `[magick] convert` but the syntax to generate the proper output name is a bit contrived. But you can also of course make a loop in a shell script instead.

Answer (score -1):

I used Meitu app, which supports batch processing to make photos at the same size.